# executing source command with JSch

Tags: java, linux, jsch

I have to two scripts, I want to execute on a server. The problem is, that the frist script sets some environment variables and has to be executed via

```
. script1.ksh
```

while the second can be executed just by

```
script2.ksh
```

Now if I give Jsch the following String to execute

```
cd work_dir && . script1.ksh && ./script2.ksh
```

It tells me script1.ksh not found
Whil if I try

```
cd work_dir && ./script1.ksh && ./script2.ksh
```

of course the variables in script2 are not defined.

Is there any way to execute such a command in JSch?

Comment: Have you tried doing `source script1.ksh` in place of `. script1.ksh`?

Comment: yes, tell me "source" not found, thanks anyway

Comment: `. ./script1.ksh`?

Comment: thanks but the same result as above, the variables for script2 are not defined afterwards

Answer (score -1):

The last answer in this post did the trick:

[Multiple commands through Jsch Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831594/multiple-commands-through-jsch-shell/5831846#5831846)

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(scpInfo.getUsername(), scpInfo.getIP(), scpInfo.getPort());
    session.setPassword(scpInfo.getPassword());
    setUpHostKey(session);
    session.connect();

    Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");//only shell  
    channel.setOutputStream(System.out); 
    PrintStream shellStream = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());  // printStream for convenience 
    channel.connect(); 
    for(String command: commands) {
        shellStream.println(command); 
        shellStream.flush();
    }

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
```

very important to sleep before the disconnection