# Executing ssh on remote server to jump to another server and execute further commands there using Java and JSch

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch

I am trying to execute multiple commands on remote machine though SSH using the JSch library. i am almost there but stuck in one command.

I am using two remote machines lets say RM1 and RM2

Able to do following steps,

1. Able to connect to remote machine RM1.
2. Able to execute single/multiple commands on RM1 (followed this https://www.journaldev.com/246/jsch-example-java-ssh-unix-server and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5831846/8773024 ).
3. Able to connect to remote machine RM1 and again connect to another remote machine RM2.

Not able to do this step,
1. Once i will be connected to remote machine RM2 after this not able to execute any command.

Please let me know if anyone can help me on this.

I tried this code:

```
String host="IP";
String user="username";
String password="password";
String command1="pwd";
String command2="ssh -tt user@ip";
String command3="pwd";

java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
System.out.println("Connected");        

Channel channel1=session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel1).setCommand(command1;command2;command3);

channel1.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec)channel1).setErrStream(System.err);            
InputStream in1=channel1.getInputStream();
channel1.connect();
byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
while(true){
  while(in1.available()>0){
    int i=in1.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
    if(i<0)break;
    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
  }
  if(channel1.isConnected()){
    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel1.getExitStatus());
    break;
  }
  try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
}
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
System.out.println("DONE");
```

Comment: Did you try executing `pwd;ssh -tt user@ip;pwd` in a normal SSH terminal client connected to the RM1? Does it do what you want? => It does not! – So why do you expect it to work in Java?

Comment: Btw, to do the "jump", you should use port forwarding (See JSch [`JumpHosts` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html)), instead of executing `ssh` on the jump server.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl manually these command does not work on SSH terminal; i had tried this " pwd;ls;pwd; "  in my code and it worked, so i thought of doing some workaround.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I checked link shared by you and followed same, but now i am getting   error "Auth fail" Please let me know if you can help me in this?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl hey, i have added new code as well in my question, please check and let me know?
I am new in java language, so i kept this code as simple as possible.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? Show us [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848) for both sessions. + How are you authenticating from RM1 to RM2 when connecting manually?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have added log as well. I have added comment ("code is failing in this step") where my code is failing please check once. 
actually i had one doubt, do i need to add RM1 public key?

Comment: I am able to connect to connect to RM1, and then ssh to RM2 and then run multiple commands on RM2 (manually)

Comment: But how are you authenticating to RM2? Show us output of `ssh -v user@rm2`. Are you are using public key authentication? Then you need to specify the private key in your code.

Comment: Should i add private key of RM1? can i take reference from here https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/com.jcraft.jsch.JSch/addIdentity?snippet=5ce6b2bc7e03440004e9b48d.
i tried following : String privKey = xyz //(priv key of RM1);  jsch.addIdentity(privKey ); session.connect(); // connecting to RM2 
but it failed with error " system can not find the path specified"

Comment: I guess that the file does not exist on your *local* machine, right?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl previous error got fixed. I added private key step in my code, but still getting auth fail error. i have updated my code as well as error. please check.

Comment: What is *"priv_k of RM1"*? You need to add a private key for authentication to RM2.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl private key of which machine ? localhost, RM1 or RM2 ? i have tried with private key of RM1 machine and localhost.

Comment: Again, *"private key **for authentication to RM2**"*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl RM2 was down thats why i was not able to connect. I tried with some other remote machine and i was able to connect and print "ls" output, even without using private key. Thanks you so much Martin for following up. :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing `pwd;ssh -tt user@ip;pwd` in a normal SSH terminal client connected to the RM1. It won't work, So it won't work in Java either.

To do the "jump", you should use port forwarding (See [JSch `JumpHosts` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html)), instead of executing `ssh` on the jump server.